# Redshift and ultra wide tables

Tags: amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

In attempt to handle custom fields for specific objects in multi-tenant dimensional DW I created ultra wide denormalized dimension table (hundreds of columns, hard coded limit of column) that Redshift is not liking too much ;).

> user1|attr1|attr2...attr500

Even innocent update query on single column on handful of records takes approximately 20 seconds. (Which is kind of surprising as I would guess it shouldn't be such a problem on columnar database.)

Any pointer how to modify design for better reporting from normalized source table (one user has multiple different attributes, one attribute is one line) to denormalized (one row per user with generic columns, different for each of the tenants)?

Or anyone tried to perform transposing (pivoting) of normalized records into denormalized view (table) in Redshift? I am worried about performance.

Comment: Could you please clarify -- are you saying that SELECT performance is poor, or only UPDATE performance? (Redshift is optimized for querying, not for updating.) How many rows are in the table, and how many rows are being updated? Are you using SORTKEY and DISTKEY on the table? Can you provide a sample of your queries to demonstrate your situation? Thank you.

Comment: Table is small (stage table), lets say tens/hundreds of records, but hundreds of columns. Query would be something like: _update stage set validFrom = sysdate, validTo = 2999-01-01_. Planner tells me it is doing 'Sequential Scan'.

Answer (score 4):

Probably important to think about *how* Redshift stores data and then implements updates on that data.

Each column is stored in it's own sequence of 1MB blocks and the *content* of those blocks is determined by the `SORTKEY`. So, how ever many rows of the sort key's values can fit in 1MB is how many (and which) values are in corresponding 1MB for all other columns.

When you ask Redshift to `UPDATE` a row it actually writes a new version of the entire block for **all columns** that correspond to that row - not just the block(s) which change. If you have 1,600 columns that means updating a single row requires Redshift to write a *minimum* of 1,600MB of new data to disk.

This issue can be amplified if your update touches many rows that are not located together. I'd strongly suggest choosing a `SORTKEY` that corresponds closely to the range of data being updated to minimise the volume of writes.

Comment: I was wondering if Redshift is touching only modified column (as I expected) or it need to delete and insert new records to all columns (as you mention). It seems that later is true and you are right (which is kinda surprising, but I dont know internals of columnar database so deep to understand why it is doing. Learn something new every day :).)

Comment: I believe it has to do with the MVCC transaction approach they use. Changes are rolled back by killing the new blocks and removing the tombstone from the previous blocks. I guess you could make that work with single column blocks but you'd need to track the epoch per column instead of per table.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of with ultra-wide tables in Redshift is they eat insane amounts of disk space. Real example we have in production: 3600 rows, 1600 cols, 44KB gzipped in S3, 128GB in Redshift. 

Comment: Lol. BTW you are able to vacuum such a monster? Or you are always dropping, reloading in sorted way?

Comment: That particular table (and others of the same ilk) just get reloaded.